# Pixelation of PIL generated image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I am trying to generate PDF files from generated image. The generated PDF file has high level of pixelation on zooming in which is creating shadows during printing.

**Image of zoomed in qrcode from PDF**

Showing gray zone around qrcode modules and pixels (gray) which should be white otherwise. It does not matter if the desired_resolution matches or is lower than the resolution in which the original image was created.

[image]

What could be the issue and possible fixes?

```
qr_size_mm = 8
MM2PX_FACTOR = 94.48  # 2400 dpi

def create_code(prefix, number, postfix=None):
    message = prefix + str(number)
    message += postfix if postfix is not None else ""
    series_qrcode = pyqrcode.create(message, error='H', version=3, mode='binary')
    # print(series_qrcode.get_png_size())
    binary = BytesIO()
    desired_scale = int(qr_size_px / series_qrcode.get_png_size())
    series_qrcode.png(binary, scale=desired_scale, module_color=(0, 0, 0),
                      background=(255, 255, 255), quiet_zone=3)

    tmpIm = Image.open(binary).convert('RGB')
    qr_dim = tmpIm.getbbox()
    # print(qr_dim)
    return tmpIm, qr_dim

qr_size_px = int(qr_size_mm * MM2PX_FACTOR)
# create A4 canvas
paper_width_mm = 210
paper_height_mm = 297
start_offset_mm = 10
start_offset_px = start_offset_mm * MM2PX_FACTOR

canvas_width_px = int(paper_width_mm * MM2PX_FACTOR)
canvas_height_px = int(paper_height_mm * MM2PX_FACTOR)
pil_paper_canvas = Image.new('RGB', (canvas_width_px, canvas_height_px), (255, 255, 255))

# desired pixels for 1200 dpi print
required_resolution_px = 94.48  # 47.244     # 23.622
required_resolution = 2400

print("Page dimension {page_width} {page_height} offset {offset}".format(page_width=canvas_width_px, page_height=canvas_height_px, offset=start_offset_px))
start_range = 10000100000000
for n in range(0, 5):
    print("Generating ", start_range+n)
    qr_image, qr_box = create_code("TLTR", number=start_range+n)
    # qr_image.show()
    print("qr_box ", qr_box)
    qr_x = int(start_offset_px + ((n+1) * qr_box[2]))
    qr_y = int(start_offset_px)
    print("pasting at ", qr_x, qr_y)
    pil_paper_canvas.paste(qr_image, (qr_x, qr_y))

    # create a canvas just for current qrcode
    one_qr_canvas = Image.new('RGB', (int(10*MM2PX_FACTOR), int(10*MM2PX_FACTOR)), (255, 255, 255))
    qrXY = int((10*MM2PX_FACTOR - qr_box[2]) / 2)
    one_qr_canvas.paste(qr_image, (qrXY, qrXY))
    one_qr_canvas = one_qr_canvas.resize((int(qr_size_mm*required_resolution_px),
                                          int(qr_size_mm*required_resolution_px)))
    one_qr_canvas.save(form_full_path("TLTR"+str(start_range+n)+".pdf"), dpi=(required_resolution, required_resolution))


pil_paper_canvas = pil_paper_canvas.resize((int(paper_width_mm*required_resolution_px),
                                            int(paper_height_mm*required_resolution_px)))
# pil_paper_canvas.show()
pil_paper_canvas.save(form_full_path("TLTR_qr_A4.pdf"), dpi=(required_resolution, required_resolution))
```

Comment: Would appreciate any comment on this or direction to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like anti-aliasing to me, inherent to the PDF format, but I am not an expert on the matter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing

Comment: Thanks for your comments @physicalattraction.
Tried changing resizing from fixed size to scale/factor which didn't help. Realized then that PDF inherently saves at 96dpi which is what was messing up my prints. Will try anti-aliasing as well.

Comment: Do your `resize()` commands have an option to use *"NEAREST NEIGHBOUR"* sampling instead of bilinear or bicubic?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, it (PIL) does, currently using BILINEAR. For qrcode from binary to PIL, i am upscaling the image, in the later stage while saving, I may be retaining the scale or downscale depending on the MM2PX_FACTOR.
I realized that the biggest issue is to do with PDF being saved which is significantly downscaling the resolution (DPI) of the image using PIL. I am yet to find a way in PIL to save print-ready PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I incorporated 3 changes to fix/workaround the issue:

1. Instead of specifying fixed number for resizing, switched to scale (m*n).
2. Used lineType=cv2.LINE_AA for anti-aliasing as suggested by @physicalattraction

That still one issue unresolved which was that PIL generated PDF @96dpi which is not good for printing. Was unable to figure the option to use Print-ready PDF (PDF/A or something on those lines). Hence switched to generating PNG to generate high-quality qrcodes.